# Is colspan with renderDataTable possible in shiny?

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

Is it possible to use colspan with renderDataTable (or by some other hack) to produce tables like this: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

edit: also asked in the shiny group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/OQ1MNRgItn4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, have a look here https://rstudio.github.io/DT/
Section - 2.6 Custom Table Container

```
# a custom table container
sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      th(rowspan = 2, 'Species'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Sepal'),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Petal')
    ),
    tr(
      lapply(rep(c('Length', 'Width'), 2), th)
    )
  )
))
print(sketch)
```